# Slow Rendering in Mdpi and Ldpi android phones

Tags: java, box2d, libgdx

*Hi*,
 I am developing a game with the help of **LibGDX** and using **Box2d** in it. The problem is that when run my game on hdpi or tablets it run fine but in case of **ldpi** and **mdpi** the box2d bodies are not acting accordingly.

I think, it is taking much more time to render on those phones. So, how can I optimize my game for ldpi and mdpi phones.The values I am passing in world.step is`worldbox.step(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime(), 10, 2000);`

Thanks.

Comment: Whats the size of your "world" ? Do you use Meters or Pixels for your World-Size?

Comment: @CodeNoob The size of my World is 480x720 in pixels.

Comment: Then you have a Large World of 480x720 Meters, because Box2D uses a Meter-System, this should help: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/47949/getting-bodies-to-go-super-fast-in-box2d/48000

Answer (score 0):

It is bad idea to use frame rate as time step. Box2D manual says:

> A variable time step produces variable results, which makes it difficult to debug. So don't tie the time step to your frame rate (unless you really, really have to).

Also, you use too big values for velocity and position iterations. Box2D manual says:

> The suggested iteration count for Box2D is 8 for velocity and 3 for position.

Try fixed time step and recomended iteration count like this:

```
float mAccomulated = 0;
float mTimeStep = 1.0f / 60.0f;
int mVelocityIterations = 8;
int mPositionIterations = 3;

void updatePhysicWorld()
{
    float elapsed = Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();

    // take into account remainder from previous step
    elapsed += mAccomulated;

    // prevent growing up of 'elapsed' on slow system
    if (elapsed > 0.1) elapsed = 0.1;
    float acc = 0;

    // use all awailable time
    for (acc = mTimeStep; acc < elapsed; acc += mTimeStep)
    {
        mWorld->Step(mTimeStep, mVelocityIterations, mPositionIterations);
        mWorld->ClearForces();
    }

    // remember not used time
    mAccomulated = elapsed - (acc - mTimeStep);
}
```